# get results from database in php and output them as a loop for displaying in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i have this code im working on im trying to output this :

```
{
    title:"<?php echo $sender_fullname; ?>",
    mp3:"link",
},
```

using this in php to display it in javascript

```
//database include
require_once "db.php";

//get email from session 
$email = $_SESSION['username'];

//fetch user fullname and  id based on session
$name_query = mysql_query("SELECT fullname,id FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
$name = mysql_fetch_object($name_query);

//fecth sender id, receiver id, audioclip, fullname and email
$query = "SELECT m.sender,m.receiver, m.audioclip, u.fullname, u.email 
                     FROM `users` AS u 
                     JOIN `messages` AS m ON m.receiver = u.id 
                     WHERE u.email = '".$email."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

here's the loop what should i do to output the same

```
while(
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $sender = $row['sender'];
        $sender_name_query = mysql_query("SELECT fullname FROM users WHERE id = '$sender'");
        $sender_name = mysql_fetch_object($sender_name_query);
        $sender_fullname = $sender_name->fullname;
        echo '{<br/>title:".'$sender_fullname'.",<br/>mp3:"link",<br/>},';      
    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: now im geting this error
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in... on line 34
`
while(
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
 $sender = $row['sender'];
 $sender_name_query = mysql_query("SELECT fullname FROM users WHERE id = '$sender'");
 $sender_name = mysql_fetch_object($sender_name_query);
 $sender_fullname = $sender_name->fullname;
 echo '{<br/>title:".'$sender_fullname'.",<br/>mp3:"link",<br/>},' ;  
}`
line 34
`echo '{<br/>title:".'$sender_fullname'.",<br/>mp3:"link",<br/>},' ;`

Comment: I've added an answer what's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

you can do some like :

```
while(
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $sender = $row['sender'];
        $sender_name_query = mysql_query("SELECT fullname FROM users WHERE id = '$sender'");
        $sender_name = mysql_fetch_object($sender_name_query);
        $sender_fullname = $sender_name->fullname;
        echo '{<br/>title:".'$sender_fullname'.",<br/>mp3:"link",<br/>},';
        print "<script>alert(\"$sender_fillname\")</script>";
    }
```

and then the code into the script tag run like javascript code if you wants puts the value of a php variable into a javascript variable you can do :

```
<?
    $mivar = "hola mundo";
    print "<script>";
    print "var mivar = \"$mivar\"";
    print "</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get php into javascript is to use JSON via php's  [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $sender = $row['sender'];
    $sender_name_query = mysql_query("SELECT fullname FROM users WHERE id = '$sender'");
    $sender_name = mysql_fetch_object($sender_name_query);
    $sender_fullname = $sender_name->fullname;
    $row['sender'] = $sender_fullname;
    $rows[] = $row;
}   

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "var rows = " . json_encode($rows) . ";";
echo "</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the last line:

```
echo '{<br/>title:".'$sender_fullname'.",<br/>mp3:"link",<br/>},';
```

It should be this:

```
echo '{<br/>title:"' . $sender_fullname . '",<br/>mp3:"link",<br/>},';
```

---

**Note 1**

You can write this:

```
$sender_fullname = $sender_name->fullname;
echo '{<br/>title:"' . $sender_fullname . '",<br/>mp3:"link",<br/>},';
```

easily as:

```
echo '{<br/>title:"' . $sender_name->fullname. '",<br/>mp3:"link",<br/>},';
```

---

**Note 2**

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

<sup>from http://brightmeup.info/comment.html</sup>